# Why is angular throwing error: angular.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am an angular novice.

A more descriptive error can be found [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=wtApp&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:nomod%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.5.7%2F$injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3DwtApp%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Error%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.7%2Fangular.min.js:6:412%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.7%2Fangular.min.js:25:72%0A%20%20%20%20at%20b%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.7%2Fangular.min.js:24:115)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.7%2Fangular.min.js:24:358%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.7%2Fangular.min.js:39:374%0A%20%20%20%20at%20r%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.7%2Fangular.min.js:7:355)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.7%2Fangular.min.js:39:222)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20db%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.7%2Fangular.min.js:43:246)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20c%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.7%2Fangular.min.js:20:359):

This error cropped up unexpectedly. I was trying to include BootstrapDialog but the load sequence caused bootstrap-dialog.js to load after a module that called it.

When I debugged bootstrap-dialog I found that if I stepped through the script until another `<script>` was executing that the error did not occur. This behaviour is confusing to me. Hopefully, someone with more angular experience can unravel this problem.

Script References:

```
<scriptk="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-dialog.js"></script>
<script async defer src="js/recaptcha.js"></script>
<script async defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/9f2a0d923f.js"></script>
<script async defer src="js/pages.js"></script>
<script async defer src="js/common.js"></script>
```

Complete index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" data-ng-app="wtApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!--        <META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW"> -->
        <meta name="fragment" content="!">
        <meta name="google-site-verification" content="k-yDmol0MzU1QXaTTGlhNa_gVLzUs" />
        <title>Writer's Tryst, where authors, publishers, producers, agents meet.</title>
        <meta name="description" content="A better way for writers to find publishers, producers and agents" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="Writer's Tryst, authors, publishers, producers, agents, writers, genres, manuscripts, books,   find, meet." />
        <base href="/" />
        <link  href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster+Two:700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize-min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-dialog.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/shares.css" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/icons/writers-tryst.png" />
    </head>
    <body data-ng-controller="mainController">
        <script>
            (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
            (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
            m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
            })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

            ga('create', 'UA-79802711-1', 'auto');
            ga('send', 'pageview');

        </script>
        <header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-light">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Writers-Tryst">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                        </button>
                        <div style="display: inline-block">
                            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img id="logo" src="img/writers-tryst-logo-min.png" alt="logo" /></a><br/><br/>
                            <div id="shares" class="row">   
                                <!-- Twitter -->
                                <a href="http://twitter.com/share?url=writers.tryst.ron-tornambe.com&text=<TEXT>&via=<VIA>" target="_blank" title="twitter" class="share-btn twitter">
                                    <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
                                </a>

                                <!-- Facebook -->
                                <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://writers.tryst.com" target="_blank" title="facebook" class="share-btn facebook">
                                    <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
                                </a>

                                <!-- StumbleUpon (url, title) 
                                <a href="http://www.stumbleupon.com/submit?url=http://writers.tryst.com&title=<TITLE>" target="_blank" class="share-btn stumbleupon" title="stumble-upon">
                                    <i class="fa fa-stumbleupon-circle"></i>
                                </a> -->
                                <!-- Reddit (url, title)
                                <a href="http://reddit.com/submit?url=http://writers.tryst.com&title=<TITLE>" target="_blank" class="share-btn reddit" title="reddit">
                                    <i class="fa fa-reddit-square"></i>
                                </a>  -->
                                <!-- LinkedIn -->
                                <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?url=http://writers.tryst.com&title=<TITLE>&summary=<SUMMARY>&source=<SOURCE_URL>" target="_blank" title="linked-in" class="share-btn linkedin">
                                    <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i>
                                </a>
                                <!-- Google Plus -->
                                <a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=writers.tryst.ron-tornambe.com" target="_blank" title="google+" class="share-btn google-plus">
                                    <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div> <!--navbar-header-->
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="Writers-Tryst">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li class="active"><a id="homepage" href="#/"><i class="acctive glyphicon glyphicon-home fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#writers" id="writers-link" class="fa fa-book" > Writers</a></li> 
                            <li><a href="#enablers" id="enablers-link" class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" > Enablers</a></li> 
                            <li><a href="#about" class="fa fa-info-circle"> About</a></li> 
                            <li><a href="#privacy" class="fa fa-user-secret"> Privacy/Rules</a></li> 
                            <li><a href="#contact" class="fa fa-envelope-o"> Contact</a></li> 
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a id="login" href="#log-in"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> Log-In</a></li> 
                            <li><a id="accounts-link" href="#accounts"><i class="fa fa-user hidden"></i> Create Account</a></li> 
                            <li class="dropdown" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="bottom" >
                                <button class="btn btn-custom-primary dropdown-toggle fa fa-user" style="margin-top: 8px;" data-html="true" type="button" id="user-dropdown-link" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="caret"></span></button></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" data-aria-labelledby="create-account-link">
                                    <li><a id="update-profile" href="#update-profile" class="fa fa-database"> Update profile</a></li>
                                    <li><a id="manage-uploads" href="#manage-uploads" class="fa fa-book"> Manage uploads</a></li>
                                    <li><a id="review-submissions" href="#review-submissions" class="fa fa-book"> Review Submissions</a></li>
                                    <li><a id="update-submissions" href="#update-submissions" class="fa fa-book"> Update Reviews</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li ><a id="reset-pwd-link" href="#reset-pwd"></a></li> 
                        </ul>
                    </div> <!--navbar-collapse-->
                </div> <!--container fluid-->
            </nav>
        </header>
        <div>
            <div id="message" class="alert m-t-10 m-b-10"></div> 
            <div id="main" class="content">
                <!-- angular templating -->
                <!-- this is where content will be injected -->
                <div data-ng-view></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default panel-transparent">
            <div id="foot" class="text-right small">&#169; 2016 Ronald Tornambe, Inc.</div>
        </div>
        <div id="recaptchaModal" class="modal fade hidden" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <div class="capatcha">
                            <div id="recaptcha-elements"></div>
                        </div>
                        <button type="button" id="closeModal" class="btn btn-custom-success btn-block" disabled data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>                            
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap-dialog.js"></script>
        <script async defer src="js/recaptcha.js"></script>
        <script async defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/9f2a0d923f.js"></script>
        <script async defer src="js/pages.js"></script>
        <script async defer src="js/common.js"></script>
        <script>
            $("#drop-toggle-1").on("click", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            });
            $("#accounts-link").addClass("hidden");
            angular.element(document).ready(function () {
                $("#review-submissions").on("mousedown", function () {
                    sessionStorage.setItem("submissions", "review");
                });
                $("#update-submissions").on("mousedown", function () {
                    sessionStorage.setItem("submissions", "update");
                });
            });
        </script>        
    </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var navbarColor = "#f89c00";
var navbarSelectedColor = "#e05c00";
var wtApp = angular.module('wtApp', ['ngRoute'])

    .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        // route for the home page
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
            controller: 'mainController'
        })
        // route for the writers page
        .when('/writers', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/writers.html',
            controller: 'writersController'
        })

        // route for the enablers page
        .when('/enablers', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/enablers.html',
            controller: 'enablersController'
        })
        // route for privacy/rues
        .when('/privacy', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/privacy.html',
            controller: 'privacyController'
        })
        // route for the about page
        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/about.html',
            controller: 'aboutController'
        })
        // route for the contact pagefa
        .when('/contact', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/contact.html',
            controller: 'contactController'
        })
        // route for the log-in page
        .when('/log-in', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/login.html',
            controller: 'loginController'
        })
        // route for the create account
        .when('/accounts', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/accounts.html',
            controller: 'createAccountController'
        })
        // route for the update profile 
        .when('/reset-pwd', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/reset-pwd.html'
        })
        // route for the update profile 
        .when('/update-profile', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/update-profile.html',
            controller: 'updateProfileController'
        })
        .when('/review-submissions', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/review-submissions.html',
            controller: 'reviewSubmissionsController'
        })
        .when('/update-submissions', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/review-submissions.html',
            controller: 'updateSubmissionsController'
        })
        // route for manage uploads
        .when('/manage-uploads', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/manage-uploads.html',
            controller: 'manageUploadsController'
        });
//    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});

// create the controller and inject Angular's $scope
wtApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
    $scope.example2model = []; $scope.example2data = [ {id: 1, label: "David"}, {id: 2, label: "Jhon"}, {id: 3, label: "Danny"}]; $scope.example2settings = {displayProp: 'id'};
    resetNavbar();
    $("a[href$='']").css({color:navbarSelectedColor});
});

wtApp.controller('writersController', function ($scope, $timeout) {
    resetNavbar();
    $("a[href$='writers']").css({ color: navbarSelectedColor });
    $timeout(function () {
        var form = $("#form-writers");
        var sw = (form.width() - 232) / 2;
//        $("#recaptcha-elements").parent().css("margin-left", sw );
    }, 100);
});

wtApp.controller('enablersController', function ($scope) {
    resetNavbar();
    $("a[href$='enablers']").css({ color: navbarSelectedColor });

});
wtApp.controller('aboutController', function($scope) {
    resetNavbar();
    $("a[href$='about']").css({color:navbarSelectedColor});
});
wtApp.controller('privacyController', function($scope) {
    resetNavbar();
    $("a[href$='privacy']").css({color:navbarSelectedColor});
});
wtApp.controller('contactController', function($scope) {
    resetNavbar();
    $("a[href$='contact']").css({color:navbarSelectedColor});
});
wtApp.controller('loginController', function ($scope) {
//    clearAuthenticationFlag();
    resetNavbar();
    $("a[href$='log-in']").css({ color: navbarSelectedColor });
});
wtApp.controller('createAccountController', function ($scope, $timeout) {
    resetNavbar();
    $("a[href$='create-account']").css({ color: navbarSelectedColor });
    //    clearAuthenticationFlag();

    $scope.$on('$viewLoaded', function (event) {
        $timeout(function () {
            var form = $("#form-accounts");
            if (form.length) {
                form.get(0).reset();
            }
        }, 100);
    });
});
wtApp.controller('ResetPasswordController', function ($scope) {
    resetNavbar();
});
wtApp.controller('updateProfileController', function ($scope) {
    resetNavbar();
    $("a[href$='update-profile']").css({ color: navbarSelectedColor });
});
wtApp.controller('reviewSubmissionsController', function ($scope) {
    resetNavbar();
    $("a[href$='review-submissions']").css({ color: navbarSelectedColor });
});
wtApp.controller('updateSubmissionsController', function ($scope) {
    resetNavbar();
    $("a[href$='update-submissions']").css({ color: navbarSelectedColor });
});
wtApp.controller('manageUploadsController', function ($scope) {
    resetNavbar();
    $("a[href$='manage-uploads']").css({ color: navbarSelectedColor });
});
function resetNavbar() {
    $(".navbar-collapse a").not("a[href='#']").each(function () {
        $(this).css({ 'color': navbarColor })
    });
}
```

Comment: Where do you load/include `app.js` script in the HTML?

Comment: It is actually called pages.js. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I think the problem is with the async attribute pass to the script tag. Somehow your pages.js is loading first before your angular Route loads. Try removing that tag, if that helps

Comment: That did it, Rahul. I just removed  the async from pages.js and it worked. Thanks. If you would like to create an answer, I would be happy to accept it.

Comment: Hey @rontornambe, I already created an answer. If you can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with the **async** attribute pass to the script tag. Somehow your pages.js is loading first before your angular Route loads. Try removing that tag, if that helps

For more information on this topic, you can visit 
http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2014/02/async-vs-defer-attributes.html